# JavaScript - Como saber cuantos elementos hay en un archivo JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Tengo en mi "pck.json"

```
{
    "Datos":
    [
        {
            "Nombre":"Alekz"
        },
        {
            "Nombre":"Andrea"
        },
        {
            "Nombre":"Janny"
        },
        {
            "Nombre":"Haytham"
        }
    ],
    "Datos2":
    [
        {
            "Nombre":"Alekz"
        },
        {
            "Nombre":"Andrea"
        },
        {
            "Nombre":"Janny"
        },
        {
            "Nombre":"Haytham"
        }
    ],
    "Datos3":
    [
        {
            "Nombre":"Alekz"
        },
        {
            "Nombre":"Andrea"
        },
        {
            "Nombre":"Janny"
        },
        {
            "Nombre":"Haytham"
        }
    ]
}
```

En JQuery tengo

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var obj = $.getJSON('pck.json',function(data){
        var name = data.Datos;
        var cont = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
            var object = name[i];
            //alert(name.length);
            for (property in object) {
                var valor = object[property];
                $(".unatabla").append("<tr><td>"+cont+"</td><td>"+valor+"</td></tr>");
                cont+=1;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

De qué forma puedo contar los elementos dentro del JSON, o sea que me dé como resultado 3 debido a que en el JSON están "Datos","Datos2", y "Datos3".
Por favor, gracias.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Obteniendo la propiedad length de las "keys" del objeto, se puede hacer con javascript puro (vanilla):

```
Object.keys(data).length;
```

Para referencias al respecto:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys